# Responsive flat panel in react-360

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-360

I would like to make responsive flat panel - on a mobile device should be in full screen like there
https://tour.croptrust.org/ 
[image]

Is there a possibility to achieve that in react-360.

Here is my example https://gstuczynski.com/tour/plaszow/  - try to hit loupe -> on the desktop looks good but how to make it responsive? 
Here is my code
https://github.com/gstuczynski/plaszow-cc-virtual-tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to set your surface size based on whether user is on mobile or desktop, I'd approach this by building a `NativeModule` to check if the device is mobile on `componentDidMount()` and using the built in `resize()` function to adjust your surface sizes.

First add a module in `client.js`

```
    function init(bundle, parent, options = {}) {
      const r360 = new ReactInstance(bundle, parent, {
        nativeModules: [
       //new module added here
       ctx => new SurfaceModule(ctx),
      ],
        fullScreen: true,
        ...options,
      });
    }
```

In your case you already have vars for the surfaces - but remove const to expose them to your `NativeModule`:

```
infoPanel = new Surface(1440, 850, Surface.SurfaceShape.Flat);
mapPanel = new Surface(850, 800, Surface.SurfaceShape.Flat);
cylinderSurface = new Surface(4096, 720, Surface.SurfaceShape.Cylinder);
```

Next, create your class `SurfaceModule` and include a function to check for mobile and include a ref for the surface name`checkMobile(surfaceName)`

```
        import {Module} from 'react-360-web';

        export default class SurfaceModule extends Module {
          constructor(ctx) {
            super('SurfaceModule');
            this._ctx = ctx;
          }

          checkMobile(surfaceName, id) {
              if (navigator.userAgent.match('add your match criteria here')) 
              {
                  let swidth = screen.width
                  let sheight = screen.height
                  surfaceName.resize(swidth, sheight);
                  this._ctx.invokeCallback(
                  id, 
                  [swidth, sheight] 
                 );
              }
          }

        }
```

Finally in index.js run the function to check and adjust surface sizes.

With this setup you'll need to call the function for each Surface you want to check or you could rework to send multiple refs and perform an if/switch

You could also move the call out of `componentDidMount()` into another func

```
import {
  NativeModules
} from 'react-360';

const SurfaceModule = NativeModules.SurfaceModule;
  componentDidMount() {
     SurfaceModule.checkMobile((swidth, sheight) => {
     console.log(swidth);
     console.log(sheight);
     });
  }
```

EDIT: Updated checkMobile() func & index.js to include callback